# Failed opening required bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php in an online script made with laravel

Tags: laravel, vendor

I just got a script from a friend and was written with the laravel framework. After uploading the script to my file manager, i am having this error

```html
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\bin\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\bin\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\bin\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\bin\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
```

From the error, i saw that the vendor folder was missing in my files and my friend also didnt have it.

I saw many articles talking about installing composer but i'm not having the laravel framework and the project is already on a web server.
Things i have tried.
I have copied other "vendor folder" from other laravel script i have, doesnt work.
I also tried installing composer on my pc and copied the vendor folder generated. still doesnt work
Please i will be very happy if anybody can help with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, I also put the file in the htdocs folder of my xampp locally and still having the same issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

IF you try upload your project to web hosting. follow this step.

1. compress whole project on your xampp/wampp/etc with zip extension
2. upload to your web hosting.
3. extract the file
4. create "Laravel" Directory
5. Move All Your File (your laravel Project) to "Laravel" Directory, **EXCEPT** "Public" directory.
6. open your "Public" directory, and move to public_html or parent directory or one step before your "Public" directory ("../")
7. edit your index.php (previously in "Public" Directory)
8. Edit this code

require **DIR**.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

to

```
require __DIR__.'/laravel/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

9. and don't forget update your database connection on your .env file :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have found a way of generating the vendor folder, by downloading composer and navigating to the file folder in htdocs, then run composer installer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way of generating the folder and it works.
I install composer for windows on my system , then navigate to the htdocs folder in xamp where i kept the file. then run this command
--composer installer--
After some mins, it downloaded some files and generate the vendor file itself.
i then zip the folder and upload it to my web host
Thanks every one